# Вызвать метод сервиса из другого класса без использования DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

В Startup.cs

добавлен сервис:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();
}
```

В методе Configure, класса Startup могу вызвать необходимый метод GetAsync

```
public void Configure{
var MyService = ((IMyService)app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IMyService)));
var x = MyService.GetAsync("123").Result;
}
```

Можно ли каким то образом вызвать метод этого сервиса из другого класса, не используя Dependency injection.

В мануалах читал что DI наиболее правильный способ, но у меня куча зависимых классов друг от друга и сделать через внедрение зависимостей сложно.

Comment: Хм, а вы уверены, что верно понимаете суть этого всего? Если да, то я не понимаю тогда это: `но у меня куча зависимых классов друг от друга` и почему `сделать через внедрение зависимостей сложно`?

Comment: `но...куча зависимых классов...через внедрение зависимостей сложно` как раз должно быть всё наоборот.

Comment: С DI как раз вызывать проще, поэтому вероятно у вас видимость, что DI кагбэ есть, но по факту нет и сервисы зависящие друг от друга нафигачены по старинке с кучей взаимозависимостей? Что ж тогда - `new Service().Method(` и непонятно в чём тогда суть вопроса и при чём тогда DI, если его нет и пользоваться им нельзя. Вы же так делаете всегда, если вам надо у класса вызвать метод: создаёте экземпляр, у экземпляра дёргаете метод. Ну и вперёд, как обычно, с чего вдруг ступор если всё как обычно?

Comment: Да я действительно не очень рублю в асп нет, потому и спрашиваю, как я думал, сервис подобно службе - крутится где то там в сторонке и доступен из любого места. Через нью опять же не могу вызвать метод, так как для его выполнения нужны другие методы с кучей параметров и условий.

Comment: Когда пишете, лучше обращайтесь к человеку через @, а то SO так просто не пришлет уведомления. Конкретно ваш вопрос не про Asp, он про IoC подход, контейнеры и все в этом духе. Смотрите, вы можете написать по старинке `new MyClass(someClass);`, а можете завести контейнер и зарегистрировать в нем `MyClass` и `SomeClass`, он их хранит как простой набор типов и по необходимости, реализует за вас (либо дает реализованный ранее (если синглтон)), вам достаточно прописать зависимость в конструкторе, остальное на себя возьмет контейнер.

Comment: То есть, если брать ваш код, то строкой `services.AddTransient<IMyService, MyService>();` вы регистрируете тип в контейнере, все, вам не надо беспокоится как либо о его инициализации, контейнер сделает все за вас. Чтобы получить этот тип там, где вам нужно, надо лишь попросить его через конструктор (аля `private IMyService service; public MyClass(IMyService service) { this.service = service; }`) и все, контейнер сам разберет все зависимости, проинициализирует если надо и у вас сразу будет готовый объект.

Comment: По этому, ваше `и сделать через внедрение зависимостей сложно` - это очень противоречивое заявление, ибо что легче, самому писать `new MyClass(new OtherClass(new SomeClass))` или попросить объект у контейнера, чтоб он за вас это все проинициализировал? Так что, отвечая на ваш `Можно ли` - да, можно, пишите `new MyService(зависимости)`.

Comment: А касательно `класса Startup могу вызвать необходимый метод` - вы это можете сделать также где угодно, ибо этот "конфигуратор" в ASP также находится в контейнере, вам надо лишь его попросить, что-то на подобие: `public HomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) { var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>(); service.GetAsync("123"); }`. Ну а по поводу `много зависимостей` - это означает, что вы нарушаете правила проектирования, ибо объекты должны быть ответственны за одну определенную логику, а в парадигме IoC они должны вовсе быть самостоятельными. Почитайте про IoC, советую.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Благодарю, разобрался!